# Detect space and space + shift key press on iPhone Keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to find a simple example to detect certain key events on the iPhone keyboard but am having trouble finding examples. Does anyone have simple examples? I'm attempting to do a simple substitution when the <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> keys are pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `shouldChangeTextInRange:` delegate to detect characters:

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString*)string {

    if([string isEqualToString:@"  +"]) {

        /* do something  */

    }
}
```

Comment: You will have to do some altering, but theoretically, it should.